# Why did the time freeze not work on this vinyl record?

Tags: movie, artemis-fowl

In *Artemis Fowl* (2020), the time freeze didn't affect this playing vinyl record:

[image: A record player with a record is seen in the foreground with a blurred background]

Foaly activated a time-freeze capsule in the restaurant in order to catch a full-sized troll. Why did the time freeze not affect the record player?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi stackexchange! This is a great and well-focused first question. When you get the time, please have a look at the [tour] if you haven't already

Comment: Because the time "freeze" is just one item on a long list of things they took from the books and butchered beyond belief.

Comment: there really isn't a better response than what @fez wrote. The movie looks great *mostly (casting problems much?) and if you muted the audio you could almost think you were watching a decent adaptation of the first book. The pieces are mostly all there...it's boggling how bad it turned out

Comment: I think the [Rule of Cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) applies here (warning, TVTropes link).

Comment: It was the record player that time forgot.